# How to connect / branch two metal wire cables at 90degree angle

Tags: steel, fasteners, connections, wire, tension

I have a 1mm thick wire cable that's 200cm long.

Using the same cable, at 10cm intervals, I have to branch / tee off at 90degree angles.

Some sort of tee crimp / ferrule comes to mind as a last report, but I'm wondering does a fastener for this exist?

I can imagine it would have three entry points... two for the main wire in and out, one for the branch

Comment: Wire- structural? If so, some appropriate twists with a ferule is usually one of the earlier resorts rather than last.  Be sure to load test...

Comment: So you mean a metal block with a T-channel in it and two threaded holes for clamping screws in each leg? Screws just aren't very reliable at clamping down on wire rope if you are actually planning to seriously pull on it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one is made with the top of the tee open to take the main cable.

Then the branch cable could even be wound around the main before crimping.

However, soldering might work then you could consider plastic dipping...